# Logistic Regression Analytical Solution

Tags: regression, logistic

I understand that logistic regression has no analytical solution, but I was investigating the marginal effect in a simple logistic regression and followed this train of thought to the final line. Here it seems we have an analytical solution for $\beta$, so I must have done something wrong?

[image]

Comment: How would you compute the conditional probabilities in question if you do not already have a fit logistic regression?

Comment: estimated from the sample proportions ?

Comment: If $x$ is a continuous feature, it's very likely you will not have observed any data at both some value $t$ and $t+1$.  Even if you have, different choices of reference point will give different answers.

Comment: but still, what is mathematically wrong with this statement?

Comment: or rather, I am missing some part of logistic regression that makes this obviously false, but I am not sure which part that is

Comment: Wrote an answer.

Answer (score 3):

> what is mathematically wrong with this statement?

There's nothing *mathematically* wrong with your derivation, but the symbols must be interpreted in a particular way.

The conditional probabilities in your statement *must* mean the model predictions.  Said differently, the *first* equation you write *already assumes* you have a fit logistic regression models, as the conditional probabilities in your model *are* the predictions from the model.

It no longer works if you interpret those probabilities in any other way, in particular, as empirical sample probabilities.  For example:

1) $P(Y = 1 \mid x = 0)$ may not even be approximatable from your sample, you may not observe any data points at $x=0$.

2) If your $x$ feature is continuous, you may not observe any more than one data point at *any* value of the feature.

3) There may be *no* value of $t$ for which you have observed multiple data at *both* $x = t$ and $x = t + 1$.  Even if you use other values for your separation, the same may be true.

4) Even if all the above are not a problem, you've observed many data points at values of $x$ that are spaced by some separation, using different reference points to compute your sample probabilities may lead to different answers, i.e. different values of $\beta$.

The magic of the regression model is that it gets around all these problems.  It uses all your pairs of data, with all their spacings, to estimate one value of $\beta$ that best describes them all at once.  There really is no way to do this in a simpler manner.

Comment: Okay I really like this answer except for one thing. I get how the lack of data in the real world could be a problem, but assume you have infinite data so the problems in 1,2,3 are gone. Now I claim that the above is a solution for beta....it just isn't the solution that maximizes the log likelihood of your data.UNLESS your predictor x is binary , then the above seems like a closed form because we replace x with 0 and x+1 with 1

Comment: That, I believe, is true.  In the binary case it is the beta that maximizes the log-likelihood.  In any other case, yes, it gives you a beta, but you can't call the process logistic regression.